# can we avoid session hijacking using spring security?

Tags: spring-mvc, session, cookies, spring-security, session-hijacking

We are using apache tomcat as a server for our Spring MVC based web application. If a user has been logged in from a browser let's say chrome, and we copied its JSESSIONID and pasted into another browser let's say Firefox, and then we are able to access the modules assigned to the particular user logged in from chrome to the one who is logged in from firefox.

How can we prevent such session hijacking by using spring security? or in general, which things we should code in order to get rid of session hijacking. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using cookies for session handling or REST parameters? Session cookies are not available to javascript for manipulation and so they are safe, plus changing browsers is an acceptable behaviour. Man in the middle attacks can bypass all these measures but we are not concerned with that here

Comment: thanks @NikosM. for your reply, actually JSESSIONID is a cookie generated by tomcat to manage the session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform a basic Spring Boot application security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62092295/how-to-perform-a-basic-spring-boot-application-security)

Comment: @FaustoCarvalhoMarquesSilva thanks, http-only and url appending We've already configured in our application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to make it secure and HttpOnly and it worked. 
Implementation Procedure in Apache Tomcat:
1) Open the httpd.conf file. Find the following line using CTRL + f in your text editor:

```
 #LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

2) Remove the #

3) Add following entry in httpd.conf

```
Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
```

4) Restart Apache HTTP server

Answer (score 2):

I don't think having access to a user's browser with a logged in session qualifies as "session hijacking". You can mitigate the risk using the `httpOnly` and `secure` flag when setting the cookie, thus it cannot be read by JavaScript and will only be forwarded on a secured channel (HTTPS). Walking over to someone's computer and copying the cookie from one browser to another is a whole different topic that I don't think you can do much about with Spring Security.

Comment: Thanks, Krisz. actually the same thing I've asked the security auditors but they've suggested to track the user based on IP and user-agent and restrict the access if not matched to the one user has logged in from.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's a common practice, but there's no specific, out-of-the-box solution for it using Spring Security.

Comment: @Navnath, as it is said changing browsers (eg having access to users browser directly)  does not count as session hijacking. Plus both user-agent and IP can be spoofed easily. Security frameworks dont take these cases into account. having cookies be http-ony and secure is as far as the framework can go. You can implement extra measures from that point on, but as it is said many things can be spoofed

Comment: @NikosM. Yes, extra layer of coding is added in order to avoid such a case.